# Suggestions Required - React with Redux on Nodejs server using expressjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-router-dom

I am creating a application using tech stack Reactjs, Redux, ExpressJS & I need your inputs or suggestions or example boiler plate code.

I have created and deployed my application https://protected-thicket-25204.herokuapp.com  which is working fine

But the problems are

1. Components are tightly coupled with Router as below mentioned
2. I do not have control to add new component on any Route without doing code change. I want to drive the components from database for this route these many components should load.

   ```
   <BrowserRouter>
   <Header />
   <Route exact={true} path="/search-results" component={SearchResults} />
   <Route exact={true} path="/" component={HomePage} />
   ```

Required help on

1. Is there a way from SSR(Server side rending) React components to load based on request url i can decide which all components and redux state to create.

Please do suggest if any better way can be achieved to add any component to particular URL on the fly without code deployment

Thanks,
Mohammed Farooq

Comment: take a look at react-starter-kit OR next.js.

Comment: @alieslamifard thanks for info i will go through it but it is very heavy & complex to understand.

Comment: next.js have a good documentation and really easy to understand and run, because of zero configuration for webpack and easy routing. take a look ;)

Comment: @alieslamifard Acutally I am looking for driving what components to load in a page & if required I can remove it from page using configuration from database